# Indexing Modes Of Turbo Assembler

Tags: windows, pointers, assembly, dos, tasm

Looked a lot online for an answer to this question and found nothing. 
My Question Is “How is it possible to access specific address in Assembler “
I’m asking for the actual syntax in Turbo Assembler seen things like
Mov ax , [value]
And 
Move es:[bx] , value
And I’m very confused . 
What the [value] And :[value] Syntax even mean in Turbo Assembler and how would I access a specific address like B4h for example ?

Comment: When you buy Turbo Assembler, there're included several small books with documentation, describing also full TASM syntax and much more, check your TASM package.

Comment: Haven't bought it .

Comment: Can you explain this to me please?

Comment: I'm not aware of TASM being free software... You can maybe get free modern MASM with some kind of microsoft SDK, but I haven't been there for 10+ years, not sure about current offers. And then there's world of free (in some way or all of them) software, like NASM, FASM, YASM, GNU as (gas), etc... if you have some other resources in TASM syntax, it may hurt a bit to use other tool, as it takes experience to convert between different dialects. No, I can't explain it, if you are ignorant to breach the terms of use the SW vendor opted to use, at least use your other skills to obtain help.

Comment: BTW TASM is very nice piece of SW, but currently discontinued and quite obsolete, so you are not only disrespectful to the original creators, but you are also locking yourself in some deep history. You can use NASM as replacement, the syntax dialect is similar (not same), works for 16, 32 and 64 bit x86, is constantly updated, and the source code and documentation is available for you to study. There're also some tutorials and books for it, although you will find probably more of MASM stuff, especially for old obsolete systems like DOS or MS Windows.

Comment: The assembler syntax is designed around the target processor's ISA. In this case, we are talking about 16-bit x86. If you Google for "x86 real-mode addressing modes" I'm sure something will come out, likely on this site. Alternatively, the Intel Manual 2 has a list of addressing modes. The syntax is very similar, if not identical, to what TASM used.

Comment: Thanks you I asked a few other guys I know and one had an answer for me . Appreciate your help here at stackoverflow in the assembly tag

Answer (score -2):

The “ [ Var ] “ Syntax in Turbo Assembler is simply a way to refer to the value the Var is pointing at in the case Var Holds 3Ah for example this Syntax will refer to the value of the memory address 3Ah .

Comment: If `var` **is** `3Ah`, not holds. Let me show example: `var DB 3Ah` means, that `var` has some memory address (assigned by linker and OS loader of executables), like `1200h`, and the byte value at address `1200h` is `3Ah`. Then `mov bx,OFFSET var` will load value `1200h` into `bx`. `mov bx,[var]` will load two bytes starting at address 1200h, so `bl = 3Ah`, `bh = <next_byte_in_memory_after_that_3A>`. The symbols in assembly, like `var`, are more like memory addresses/pointers/bookmarks, pointing at next byte, than "variables" containing the stuff defined after.

Comment: Try this tutorial targetting MASM: http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html  (TASM is largely compatible with MASM, depending on the command line options, for the remaining discrepancies you will very likely find some stack overflow questions explaining the subtleties, if you ever hit some problem with MASM syntax in TASM). You can also google for original TASM documentation. Imagine that, you can steal also the documentation, not only the SW, it's like 2 mouseclicks away. I wonder how you even found stackoverflow site with your effort-level...

Comment: @Ped7g what you mean by the “ Symbols in assembly” ? I meant that Var is a variable named Var . In Turbo Assembler at least Var is not a keyword (As far as I knows ... )

Comment: No, there are no variables in assembly. The "labels" you can put into code, like `print_loop:` or in data segment your "variables" like `var DB 1` are *symbols*. Try to use `/l` command line option to produce listing file, there's also table of defined symbols included (or you have to switch listing options to include symbols table, maybe it's not included by default). Check command line options manual for possible TASM options. I'm trying to show you, that it's usually better to think about them as "labels"/"memory addresses" than variables, it will be less confusing later (common pitfalls).

Comment: I mean, thinking about them as about "variables" will save you some confusion first, but will cause havoc later, like for example when above I did `mov bx,[var]`, why then I'm talking about `bl = 3Ah` and `bh = <byte_after_3A>` ... if you will learn to think about it as memory address, and computer memory content, it should make sense easily, because the `bh` is loaded by that `mov` from address `var+1`, which I didn't define, but it is there in memory right after that defined `3Ah`. Also when you will start to explore "strings", understanding that memory+addresses concept makes it much easier

Comment: @Ped7g if for example I have an 8 bit address of 00001010b stored in a symbol named Var and in the memory there’s the byte 7Bh stored In that address and I do mov bh, [Var] will bh have 7Bh inside? or it will be a pointer to 7bh (has his address stored in it , 00001010b In this case ) ?

Comment: @Ped7g I’m not new to this concept of pointers had several years of cpp and c programming .

Comment: If I understand you well, yes, bh=7Bh. In C syntax "var db 7B" is doing: `uint8_t var_content = 0x7B;` `uint8_t* var = &var_content;` ... and `mov bx,OFFSET var` is `bx = var /* == &var_content */;` ... `mov bh, [var]` is `bh = *var /* == var_content */;`.

Comment: @Ped7g thanks you for the C example I understand this much better now